# I want to validate if user phone number and email is unique and redirect on failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to validate if the phone number and email is unique, which i figured but how do i do if phone number or email is not unique send to user registration path?

I tried

```
validates :phone_number, :email, if uniqueness: false {redirect_to user_registration_path}
```

Answer (score 3):

The model is by definition unaware of the request context. You cannot perform a redirect from the model.

In order to accomplish the task, in your controller validate the instance and if invalid perform the redirect.

Here's a pseudo-code:

```
class Controller
  def action
    # instance is your instance
    if instance.valid?
      # do what you need to do
    else
      redirect_to user_registration_path
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to check this in your controller, since your model has nothing to do with redirects.

Your action could look like this:

```
class UsersController
  def some_action
    if User.where(params[:user].slice(:phone_number, :email)).exists?
      redirect_to user_registration_path
    else
      # no redirect
    end
  end
end
```

This explicitly checks if another user with the phone number and email already exists, rather than validating the instance.